# CodeChef's Subsequence Equality

Tags: c++, arrays

I am a beginner coder (I studied C++ in high school) now I started solving questions from this competitive programming website. I tried to solve this question but wasn't quite successful.

So, this is someone else code, what I cannot understand is Why they subtracted ASCII value of 'a' from string that is inside an array. Here is the question and solution:

https://www.codechef.com/problems/LIKECS01
[image]

[image]

Comment: Copy the code and use a debugger

Comment: ASCII code of `a` is 97: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `if(a[s[i]-97] >= 2)`, we are actually checking for occurrence of that particular character(s[i]) with help of array a(index 0 for a, index 1 for b, index 2 for c, and so on...)..
As 97 is ascii code of 'a' so 'a'-97 will give you 0, 'b' - 97(i.e. 98 - 97) will give 1.. and so on.

Comment: Thanks, got it now.